# To change mouse cursor on click in JointJs

Tags: jointjs

When joining processes by clicking. Once the person has clicked on the first node, the mouse pointer should change, indicating that first node has already been clicked, and now we just need to click on the target node.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user clicks on the first node, you can set a class on your application HTML container element (or even on the paper element: `paper.$el.addClass('connecting')`). Based on that class, you can set a different cursor type in your CSS:

```
.connecting {
   cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Or maybe just for JointJS elements:

```
.connecting .element {
   cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Here I'm using the 'pointer' type of cursor but you can use any of these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor. I'm also using the `!important` flag to overrule other cursor properties set by your application/JointJS. Note that you can even use images as your cursor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url, giving the user a better guidance on what he should do.